# Listbox Itemsource binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I am trying to bind my list to a listbox. Listbox binding is working but I can't bind property to item template.

Here is my class

```
public class handle{
        public string smurfName;
        internal Process process;

        public handle(Process _pro, string _smuf)
        {
            process = _pro;
            smurfName = _smuf;
        }
    }
```

Here is my window constructor.

```
public static ObservableCollection<handle> smurfList = new ObservableCollection<handle>();
    public GameMask()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            runningSmurfs.ItemsSource = smurfList;

            handle newSmurf = new handle(null, "THISNAME");
            smurfList.Add(newSmurf);
        }
```

Here is my xaml

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Margin="3,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" Name="runningSmurfs">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=smurfName}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Unfortunetely I can't see "THISNAME" on the list, but if I change Texblock Binding to a text it is working fine.

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: What do you mean by `Unfortunetely I can't see "text" on the list`

Comment: Fixed typing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged I think, but you can't bind to a field which you were trying to do

Try this:

```
public string SmurfName { get; set; }
```

and change in xaml the binding to SmurfName

Answer (score 2):

You need at least a property so your binding can work.
smurfName should be a property, better if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged too.

Comment: But it is already a property by the definition of class Handle, INotifyPropertyChanged is not needed in my case bacause I will only make addings and removings

Comment: public string smurfName; is not a property. You need a get and set

Answer (score 0):

In your handle class add a getter and setter to your `smurfName` property:

```
public string smurfName { get; set; }
```